# Weston Global Configuration

Tags: configuration, wayland

I have installed Weston, and I would like to change the keyboard default layout it uses. Is there a global file to do this in? I know I can do it on a per-user base but that seems redundant as everyone will be using the same layout.

I'm running ArchLinux if it matters.

Answer (score 4):

You can change the keyboard layout in `weston.ini` which should be placed in `~/.config`:

```
[keyboard]
keymap_rules=evdev
keymap_layout=de
```

Change `keymap_layout` according to your needs.